# Will potted HOYA grow well in Los Angeles?

Tags: plant-care

I live in Southern California (Los Angeles) and it can be quite hot and dry here (low humidity). Can I grow potted Hoya? Does it tolerate/prefer direct sunlight or just bright light? Can it be grown indoors? Where would I find it to purchase? I have never seen it in any nursery.

Thanks for your help!
Dido

Answer (score 1):

Hoya are tropical plants - they will grow outdoors provided temperatures never fall below 55degF. There are different varieties, and their requirements may differ slightly one from another, but they are generally grown as houseplants. Indoors, they prefer to have good light but no direct sun, out of cold draughts - many people grow them in hanging pots so they can trail, since they are vining plants. Hoya carnosa is probably the most commonly grown variety.

I can't advise on where you can get one, but further information on Hoya generally here http://pistilsnursery.com/hoya-plant-care/